Co-worker backstabbing
The 3-way meeting got canceled by the coworker multiple times. So I had to meet my boss privately.
I initially asked the following question and I was wondering if you can give me some insights. link
The 3 way meeting was canceled 3 times by the coworker, I went ahead and talked to my manager and showed him examples of their employees’ behavior. They agreed it was inappropriate and acknowledged that my work has been excellent. However, they still decided not to renew my contract due to budget concerns. When I asked about my application for an employee position, my manager claimed he hadn’t received it.
I know who they’re planning to hire, so I’m wondering how I should handle this. Should I reach out to HR to ask why they didn’t forward my application? It feels like they’re playing games. I notified both my manager and a colleague when I applied, yet it seems like my colleague may have influenced the situation against me. In our first meeting, my manager even mentioned that Employee A had called me “slow.” To make matters worse, my manager has let me suffer for the past 11 months dealing with these two employees by cutting my meetings and not managing me directly, which has left me very unhappy. Now it feels like they’re twisting their words.

When you asked your manager about your application, did they seem keen at all to see it?

If you get treated so poorly: why do you want to keep working there. They obviously don't want you. (for whatever reason). You do not have a carreer there. Time to move on.

“Should I reach out to HR to ask why they didn’t forward my application?” - What do you hope to achieve? You won’t be hired. If you are hired you’ll have to work with individuals who apparently are unwilling to fight to hire you. They lost your application because in all likelihood, they didn’t want to hire you for that position. You don’t sound like you want to work there beyond having a job.

You are a contractor trying to convert this into a hire? And they don’t want you?  Get another contract somewhere else.

I do not work as a contractor (moved from my permanent position two years ago), I accepted this offer with the assumption if I performed well, they would offer me a permanent job as they did for themselves, I performed well for the past two years, but they were so toxic and avoided my growth. The management was poor(did not perform well) and the two colleagues were toxic

Your desired goal of them changing their minds by not hiring someone else and then hiring you is not going to happen. They have made it clear on so many levels.
It is not fair and it is not nice but it is life.
They likely had already decided who they wanted to hire before the posted the job. I can't know that for sure - obviously, but everything about their behavior points that way.
The effort and emotional angst being expended to this disloyal group is not helpful to your career growth. I am sorry, but that is the hard truth.
We've all been treated poorly at some point in our careers. That's why it is helpful to remember that it is only a job. Yes, you should enjoy working somewhere, but it is just a job. Give it your all while you're there, but be able to walk away. They are not your family.
You have talents, otherwise they wouldn't have kept you 2 years. Use these talents to get a better paying job or gig elsewhere. Put this behind you.


When I asked about my application for an employee position, my manager claimed he hadn’t received it.

and

I know who they’re planning to hire

I do not know if it is normal, but it is something that happens in companies occasionally (or maybe even often). It even happened to me about 10-15 years ago. I sent my CV to a company - the CV was basically a copy-paste of the job posting. I received an answer that my skills do not match their needs. I replied showing clearly that my skills really match their needs. They never answered again. Obviously, I got the message and gave up.
Although it is not nice, that is (in a bad way) political correctness. They do not tell you the real reason, so they talk some small sh!t, hoping that you get the message.

it seems like my colleague may have influenced the situation against me. In our first meeting, my manager even mentioned that Employee A had called me “slow.” To make matters worse, my manager has let me suffer for the past 11 months dealing with these two employees by cutting my meetings and not managing me directly, which has left me very unhappy. Now it feels like they’re twisting their words.

So everybody in that company wants to get rid of you. It is irrelevant for what reasons, the reality is very clear.

Should I reach out to HR to ask why they didn’t forward my application?

NO! You should update your CV and send it to companies, find another job. Soon, you will not work for this company any more.
